# Allow Block Editing By User Role

Tags: user-roles, block-editor

I am looking to see what options there are for Gutenberg (or via a plug-in) to allow users with certain roles to edit blocks on pages.

Here is a general layout. Multiple pages are in the site, and each page will have specific block content (blocks will generally only be on 1 page).

[image]

When a user logs in, based on their role, they should be able to see the blocks, and if they have the correct permissions, can also edit the block. But not every block on every page can be edited by the same role, however. User 1 may only have access to edit 1 block, whereas another user can edit 3 of them, and another may be able to edit all of them.

The permissions will be set based on an Active Directory login. If the user has the correct permissions for that block, then ideally we can also show edit icons so they can edit the block inline.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.